# How to retrieve node-pool size from a k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I couldn't find useful information from:

```
gcloud container clusters describe CLUSTER_NAME
```

or from

```
gcloud container node-pools describe POOL_NAME --cluster CLUSTER_NAME
```

It is easy to scale up/down using `gcloud` tool though:

```
gcloud container clusters resize [CLUSTER_NAME] --node-pool [POOL_NAME] \
    --size [SIZE]
```

But how can I know beforehand what is the size of my node-pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the following command:

```
gcloud container clusters describe <cluster name> --zone <zone-cluster>
```

Check for the field `currentNodeCount`

Comment: I don't know how I missed it.. maybe there's no `currentNodeCount` when that is `0`. But I could retrieve it now, thanks.. although my node-pool is `1`.

Comment: You are correct, if your node-pool is `0` the `currentNodeCount` field is going to be missing from the describe.

Comment: I won't downvote but your answer does not give the size of a node-pool, it only gives the size of the entire cluster. If you only have one pool, then both sizes are the same. I have 3 different node pools so I know that `clusters.currentNodeCount` accounts for all pools

Answer (score 5):

I do not agree with the current answer because **it only gives the total size of the cluster**.

The question is about **node-pools**. I actually needed to find out the size of a pool so I give you my best shot after many hours of searching and thinking.

```
read -p 'Cluster name: ' CLUSTER_NAME
read -p 'Pool name:    ' POOL_NAME

gcloud compute instance-groups list \
 | grep "^gke-$CLUSTER_NAME-$POOL_NAME" \
 | awk '{print $6}';
```

The `gcloud` command returns 6 columns: 1-name, 6-group-size.
The name of the instance group is predictable which lets me filter by that line with `grep`.
Lastly, select the 6th column.

Hope this helps someone else save some time.

---

For some reason I overlooked the not-so-obviuos from [Migrating workloads to different machine types](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool)

```
kubectl get nodes -l cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=$POOL_NAME -o=name \
  | wc -l
```

Comment: I don't have time to test your answer now, so I'll let the community assess that. Thanks for your contribution, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

building on top of @hanzo2001 answer - something like this will probably reflect what you need:

```
kubectl get nodes -L cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool | grep -v GKE-NODEPOOL | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -r

  16 n2-standard-4-pool
   2 preempt-custom-6
   2 default-pool
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one (often overlooked/hidden) feature of the `gcloud` - `filters` and `formatters`. These can help you to get the requested information without further `awk`/`grep` -ing.

Get the current size/node count of a specific node-pool:

```sh
gcloud compute instance-groups list \
--filter "name:gke-<cluster>-<nodepool>-*" \
--format 'value(size)'
```

Example for cluster `test` and node-pool `default-pool`:

```sh
$ gcloud compute instance-groups list --filter "name:gke-test-default-pool-*" \
--format 'value(size)'
2
```

Get the current size/node count of every node-pool in the cluster you can further use:

```sh
CLUSTER=test
for nodepool in $(gcloud container node-pools list --cluster $CLUSTER --format="value(name)"); do 
  echo -n "${nodepool}: "
  gcloud compute instance-groups list \
  --filter "name:gke-${CLUSTER}-${nodepool}-*" \
  --format 'value(size)'
done
```

Other relevant resources:

- `gcloud topic filters` - gcloud `filters` reference
- `gcloud topic formats` - gcloud `formats` reference
- [GCP blog post on filtering and formatting](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/it-ops/filtering-and-formatting-fun-with)

Answer (score 0):

```bash
gcloud compute instances list --zones ${ZONE_NAME} \
  --filter "labels.goog-k8s-node-pool-name=${NODE_POOL} AND labels.goog-k8s-cluster-name=${CLUSTER_NAME}" \
  --format "value(NAME)" | wc -l | awk '{print $1}'
```

This approach doesn't rely on the naming of instance groups and ensures you get the correct node pool.

The `awk` command removes the leading white space from the `wc` output.